# SwiftUI List updating slowly on macOS12

Tags: swift, list, macos, performance, swiftui

List will create all cell when updating data on macOS12 in Xcode13, it should be lazy load. on macOS 11, iOS, iOS Simulator is OK. here is my code:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = [Item]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show List") {
                prepareData()
            }
            .padding()
            
            List(items) { item in
                Cell(item: item)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 800, height: 600)
    }
    
    func prepareData() {
        var list = [Item]()
        for _ in 1...10000 {
            let item = Item()
            list.append(item)
        }
        items = list
    }
}

struct Cell: View {
    
    static var index = 0
    
    var item: Item
    
    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
        
        Cell.index += 1
        print("Cell init - \(Cell.index)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.id)
    }
}
```

[this is running result in macOS 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weeqG.png)

[this is running result in iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nSQW.png)